# git overrides refs/notes when fetching?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-fetch, git-notes

I'm keeping my changelog in `git-notes --ref changelog` when developing. I'm always putting a note on the merge-to-master commit and push it out to three remotes (`git push <remote> refs/notes/changelog`) - but every time I forget to push to one remote and `fetch` from it, the ref gets overridden with some old version:

(Sorry for german locale)

```
$ git fetch github -p
Von github.com:<user>/<repo>
 + ca36d98d...1f3b9041 refs/notes/changelog -> refs/notes/changelog  (Aktualisierung erzwungen)
```

How to prevent that? Is it somehow related to my `.git/config`?

(excerpt from `.git/config`):

```
[remote "github"]
    url = git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/github/pr/*
    push = +refs/notes/changelog:refs/notes/changelog
    fetch = +refs/notes/changelog:refs/notes/changelog
[notes "rewrite"]
    rebase = true
    amend = true
[notes]
    rewriteRef = refs/notes/changelog
```

Comment: It seems that the `+` in the `fetch = ` and `push = ` specs in my `.git/config` allows non-fast-forward pushes of these refs. I'm removing this `+` now and time will tell whether this was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  Each `fetch` line in your `.git/config` file specifies one of however-many *default fetch refspecs* Git will use, so:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/github/pr/*
fetch = +refs/notes/changelog:refs/notes/changelog
```

provides three such refspecs.

Each refspec consists of two main parts separated by a colon: on the left there is the source reference and on the right there is the destination reference.  Asterisks `*` may be used and act mostly like shell glob `*` (as a source only; the destination `*` is replaced with whatever the source `*` matched).  **If this pair is prefixed with a plus sign `+`, the update is always forced** (as if you used `--force` on the command line).

Note that remote-tracking names such as `refs/remotes/github/master` exist in a per-remote space: you will fetch `origin`'s `master` into `refs/remotes/origin/master` which is clearly different from `refs/remotes/github/master`.  Hence it's safe, at least for all ordinary purposes, to fetch with force for such names: you cannot overwrite your own branches, which are in `refs/heads/`, nor any other remote's remote-tracking names.

This is of course *not* true for notes references in `refs/notes/`, nor for tags in `refs/tags/`, so use care with leading `+` on either of those.